# Hi, I am new to magento. I am trying to place a CSS/javascript popup in the Products/Specification page, data from the static blocks

Tags: product, php, blocks

I am trying to place a CSS/Javascript popup onhover in the Products/Specification Section. Please refer the image. Onhover on the yellow circles.
[image: Specification tab of the Product page]

I have created some static blocks, which I want to show on specification section onhover
[image: Blocks, information about specification technical terms]

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a db table like eav_attribute_label defined at `vendor/magento/module-eav/etc/db_schema.xml` that you can call however fits you best. You will need to create a new section like "manage labels" in your attribute form to link your blocks with your attributes.

[image: Screenshot from back-office]

I believe it is possible to link fields with blocks through a drop-down but I am not sure it is really user friendly and it is a bit complex to achieve. So, just have a look at `view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_attribute_add_form.xml:520`.

You can have look at the [documentation regarding the form customization](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/tutorials/admin/custom-product-creation-form/configuration/) to see how to adapt your form. It is not an easy thing to do for beginner.

Afterward, you should ask Magento to provide you with your block ID doing like in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Config.php` and you can get data from the attribute like for `Label` in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml`. Once it is done, you can call `\Magento\Cms\Model\BlockRepository::getById` with your ID.

There are dirtier ways but it can really affect performances, consistency and/or code maintainability. I am not in that type of solutions.